# Treesaverjs + iOS5 newsstand-kit

Tags: ios5, newsstand-kit

I have a working digital magazine that is based on treesaverjs. So is that possible to create a newsstand app that is able to download a whole issue of the magazine using `NKAssetDownload` into newsstand?

If it is possible, do i use the webkit api to render the output?

Answer (score 0):

NKAssetDownload can download any kind of file. I'm working on a similar project.

You could download a treesaver page and render it in a UIWebview and call that a newsstand magazine.

Personally I'm using the Baker framework for a similar project.